# Writing ArcGIS Python Script to calculate percentage of count from range of numbers?

Tags: arcpy

I have a field in my layer called ID which gives an unique ID to each polygon.

```
ObjectID     ID
1            100
2            101
3            102
```

This field can only be populated with numbers between 100 and 10000.

How do i calculate the percentage of the current numbers in relation to the range so i can assess when its getting close to the max. Ideally need it to flag at 80%.

Any help?

I am new to python.

Comment: Use a search cursor to read the values into a list then get list length you can then determine if you are close to your 80%.

Answer (score 1):

If this value is indeed unique, you can get the number of records, and divide that by 9,900 (10,000 − 100). See the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) for details.

```
import arcpy

featureclass = r"C:\data\test.shp"
result = arcpy.GetCount_management(featureclass)
count = int(result.getOutput(0))
if count / 9900 > 0.8:
    print("You are running out of ideas (pun intended)")
```